# background-color on pseudo-element hover in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, hover, background-color, pseudo-element

I'm fighting with (yet-another) IE8 bug.

Basically, I have a small square container, with an arrow inside built with the :before and :after pseudoelements. The HTML goes something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="arrow" />
</div>​
```

And the CSS for that is

```
.container {
    height: 58px;
    width: 58px;
    background-color: #2a5a2a;
}

.arrow {
    padding-top: 7px;
}

.arrow:before {
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    border-left: 12px transparent solid;
    border-right: 12px transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 13px gray solid;
    display: block;
}

.arrow:after {
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: '';
    width: 12px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 14px;

    display: block;
}
```

Now, I want the arrow inside it to change color when I hover over the container. I added this CSS:

```
.container:hover .arrow:after {
    background-color: white;
}

.container:hover .arrow:before {
    border-bottom-color: white;
}​
```

And that's where the problem begins. That works on most browsers, but on IE8 the background-color property is not overridden. So I get only the tip of the arrow with the new color, but not the square that makes the "body" of it.

To make things more interesting, if I add the following to also change the container background-color to something slightly different, then everything starts to work and the background-color for the arrow changes!

```
.container:hover {
    background-color: #2a5a2b;
}
```

If I only set the :hover status for the container, and I set THE SAME background color that it already had, then IT DOESN'T WORK. I have to change it if I want the background-color to change.

Here's a jsfiddle if you want to try it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ke2S6/ Right now it has the same background color for the container on hover, so it won't work on IE8. Change one single digit and it'll start working.

So... any ideas?

Comment: I know it would add ugly cruft, but could you put `.container` in a container of its own, then change the (hidden) background of that container when hovered? Seems that would force the browser to do its redraw, unless Triton is enough of a ... thingie ... to calculate whether anything would change. Of course, at that rate, you could just set `.container`'s container to have the same background, and make `.container` change its background to transparent on hover. Don't have a computer with IE8 left, so I can't test this.

Comment: I don't have the IE8 available now either, but I agree that it would probably fix it. In my case, we are using SASS in the project so I just extracted `.container`'s background color to a variable and set it on hover but increased by one, and that did the trick without having to change the markup. I guess it's just another bug we have to live with and find the most appropriate workaround for each case.